# Mysql - juntar pesquisas em tabelas diferentes

Tags: mysql, select

Olá tenho os seguintes comandos:

```
SELECT CASE Extract(month FROM data_cadastro) 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Janeiro' 
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Fevereiro' 
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Março' 
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril' 
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Maio' 
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Junho' 
         WHEN 7 THEN 'Julho' 
         WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto' 
         WHEN 9 THEN 'Setembro' 
         WHEN 10 THEN 'Outubro' 
         WHEN 11 THEN 'Novembro' 
         WHEN 12 THEN 'Dezembro' 
       END                           AS mes, 
       Sum(valor1 + valor2 + valor3) AS total1 
FROM   recebimentos 
WHERE  Extract(year FROM data_cadastro) = Year(Curdate()) 
GROUP  BY mes 
ORDER  BY mes DESC 


SELECT CASE Extract(month FROM data_cadastro) 
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Janeiro' 
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Fevereiro' 
         WHEN 3 THEN 'Março' 
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril' 
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Maio' 
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Junho' 
         WHEN 7 THEN 'Julho' 
         WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto' 
         WHEN 9 THEN 'Setembro' 
         WHEN 10 THEN 'Outubro' 
         WHEN 11 THEN 'Novembro' 
         WHEN 12 THEN 'Dezembro' 
       END                   AS mes, 
       Sum(valor + comissao) AS total2 
FROM   pagamentos 
WHERE  Extract(year FROM data_cadastro) = Year(Curdate()) 
GROUP  BY mes 
ORDER  BY mes DESC
```

Essas tabelas não tem relação entre elas, como faço para retornar os dois resultados em uma mesma pesquisa, agrupados por mês, mesmo que nesse mês alguma tabela esteja vazia.

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é criar um **SUBSELECT** para cada tabela "simulando" como fosse uma tabela existente e cruzá-las através do **OUTER JOIN** (esse é um tipo de join que traz o resultado das duas tabelas), veja o exemplo:

```
SELECT rec.Mes, rec.valor_recebimento, pag.valor_pagamento
    
--SUBSELECT RECEBIMENTOS
FROM (
      SELECT CASE Extract(month FROM data_cadastro) 
               WHEN 1 THEN 'Janeiro' 
               WHEN 2 THEN 'Fevereiro' 
               WHEN 3 THEN 'Março' 
               WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril' 
               WHEN 5 THEN 'Maio' 
               WHEN 6 THEN 'Junho' 
               WHEN 7 THEN 'Julho' 
               WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto' 
               WHEN 9 THEN 'Setembro' 
               WHEN 10 THEN 'Outubro' 
               WHEN 11 THEN 'Novembro' 
               WHEN 12 THEN 'Dezembro' 
             END                           AS mes, 
             Sum(valor1 + valor2 + valor3) AS valor_recebimento 
      FROM   recebimentos 
      WHERE  Extract(year FROM data_cadastro) = Year(Curdate()) 
      GROUP  BY mes 
      ORDER  BY mes DESC ) rec
      
--OUTER JOIN PARA TRAZER TODOS OS REGISTROS DAS DUAS TABELAS
--SUBSELECT PAGAMENTO
OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT CASE Extract(month FROM data_cadastro) 
                     WHEN 1 THEN 'Janeiro' 
                     WHEN 2 THEN 'Fevereiro' 
                     WHEN 3 THEN 'Março' 
                     WHEN 4 THEN 'Abril' 
                     WHEN 5 THEN 'Maio' 
                     WHEN 6 THEN 'Junho' 
                     WHEN 7 THEN 'Julho' 
                     WHEN 8 THEN 'Agosto' 
                     WHEN 9 THEN 'Setembro' 
                     WHEN 10 THEN 'Outubro' 
                     WHEN 11 THEN 'Novembro' 
                     WHEN 12 THEN 'Dezembro' 
                   END                   AS mes, 
                   Sum(valor + comissao) AS valor_pagamento 
            FROM   pagamentos 
            WHERE  Extract(year FROM data_cadastro) = Year(Curdate()) 
            GROUP  BY mes 
            ORDER  BY mes DESC ) pag
            
--CRUZAMENTO ENTRE OS SUBSELECTS
ON rec.mes = pag.mes
```

Dependendo do que você esteja fazendo o ideal é trazer o ano nas consultas e adiciona-los no **ON** do **OUTER JOIN** para que não se agrupe meses de anos distintos.